# Getting dataframe in right format for cluster analysis

Tags: r

On an example `R` dataset:

`data("USArrests")` when I use `head(USArrests)` I get the following results:

```
            Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
California    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado      7.9     204       78 38.7
```

When I use `str(USArrests)` the following results come up:

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
  $ Assault : int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
  $ UrbanPop: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
  $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
```

Even though there is another column with the different states (no column header). How do I get my data so that first column so does not appear when I use the `str` function? I have a list of countries that I'm trying to cluster, but I can't use the `scale` function as obviously first column is not numeric, but I can't create a new dataframe without that column, as I'm trying to cluster countries...

Comment: That first column shows the "row names" for your data.frame. Generally speaking it's much easier to use data.frames that do not use row names. If you just need to use scale on a subset of data.frame columns, just index the ones you don't want out: `scale(mydata[, -1])` (ignore the first column)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the state names are `rownames`, instead of a full column. You can convert rownames to a column with:

```
USArrests <- cbind(rownames(USArrests), USArrests)
```

or convert a column to rownames:

```
rownames(df) <- df$states
```

The `tibble` package also includes the useful functions: `rownames_to_column()` and `column_to_rownames()`

Comment: @Marcel This definitely still works in the current version of R. If you still have a problem, you should ask a new question. Make sure to include a reproducible [mcve] and explain how your problem is different from this one